# Shortcut to generate field from property in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, shortcut

Is there any shortcut in VS to define a field from **corresponding** property?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you mean to generate a backing store for an auto generated property:

```
 public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

To:

```
 public string _myProperty;
 public string MyProperty { 
      get { return _myProperty; } 
      set { _myProperty = value; } 
 }
```

Then **there is no shortcut that does that in Visual Studio**. Refactoring tools like [Resharper and CodeRush](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13589434/736079) offer this feature.

- In [DevExpress CodeRush Refactor](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CodeRush/CustomDocument6026) it's under <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>, <kbd>Convert to Property with Backing Store</kbd>.
- In [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Options__Languages__CSharp__Context_Actions.html) it's under <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>, <kbd>To Property with Backing Field</kbd>.

In Visual Studio, there is the ["Encapsulate field"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5adyhe9.aspx) refactoring that works the other way around <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>,<kbd>e</kbd>.

```
 public string _myProperty;
```

To:

```
 public string _myProperty;
 public string MyProperty { 
      get { return _myProperty; } 
      set { _myProperty = value; } 
 }
```

Comment: Refactoring tools like Resharper and CodeRush offer this feature, "Create Backing Store" --- where can I find that option in resharper?

Comment: Where stuff always is in Resharper ;). Under alt-enter.